# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory Throwing System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Im reinciving the following error: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException when the function that i am testing uses Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

I would like to know if exists a way to mock the method or change the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() return. Im open to suggestions..

I can't post the complete code but its something like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task someMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    var userData = new userData
    {
        Email = "test@test.com"
    };

    _someRepository.Setup(x => x.GetSomething(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(Faker());

    var service= new Service();

    // Act
    var result = await service.TestedMethod(userData);

    // Assert
    Assert.False(result.Success);
}

public class Service
{

    public async Task<ReponseViewModel> TestedMethod(userData vm)
    {
        var anything = await _someRepository.GetSomething(vm.Email);
        
        var template = GetTemplate(url);

        return something;
    }

    private string GetTemplate(string url)
    {
        var template = File.ReadAllText(
                        Path.Combine(
                            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                            "wwwroot",
                            "html",
                            "myfile.html"));

        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: abstract out the tight coupling to System.IO

Comment: Probably, the unit test runner is executed from a different directory than you expect. That's why `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` method is returning a wrong path. You can try to debug the unit test to verify this

Comment: Are you sure the exception is coming from `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and not `File.ReadAllText()`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be that the unit test runner is executed from a different location than the project output directory. That's why `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` method can return a path that is not expected by your code.

If the test assembly is located in the same folder as the production one, you can try to modify your `GetTemplate(string url)` method to fetch the executing assembly location instead of trying to fetch current directory:

```
private string GetTemplate(string url)
{
    var assemblyPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    var template = File.ReadAllText(
                    Path.Combine(
                        assemblyPath,
                        "wwwroot",
                        "html",
                        "myfile.html"));

    return template;
}
```

If the executing assembly does not help, try `Assembly.GetAssembly(Type type)` version. For the `type` argument, you can try any type from the production assembly.

Another suggestion would be to get and provide a relative or an absolute path to the template.

Comment: This might fix the test but might as well break the code by introducing the assumption that the current directory is the directory where the startup assembly resides.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's true. The test looks more like an integration test (not a pure unit test) as it uses real resources such as the template. Using a mock template directly accessible by the test assembly would be a preferred solution

Comment: Yeah that caveat is in your answer anyway, have an upvote.